# Is there a flag to disable discovery in spring cloud consul?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-consul

Is it possible to disable the service discovery in cloud consul but still keep the registration.

Similar to how one can disable the auto registration but keeps discovery like `@EnableDiscoveryClient(autoRegisters=false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring.cloud.consul.discovery.enabled=false` will disable the consul `DiscoveryClient`. There is no java/annotation way to do it.